# How to pass parameter from Ajax Request to Web API Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am looking for the way to pass the parameter from Ajax Request to Web API Controller in ASP.Net Core like `query string` in classic ASP.
I have tried below but it did not worked.

**View:**

```
"ajax":
    {
        "url": "/api/APIDirectory/GetDirectoryInfo?reqPath=@ViewBag.Title"
        "type": "POST",
        "dataType": "JSON"
    },
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetDirectoryInfo(string reqPath)
{   
    string requestPath = reqPath;
    // some code here..
}
```

Can anyone please advise the ways available to achieve this in asp.net core web api?

Comment: make sure `@ViewBag.Title` is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"ajax":
{
    "url": "/api/APIDirectory/GetDirectoryInfo"
    "type": "POST",
    "dataType": "JSON",
    "data": {"reqPath":"@ViewBag.Title"}
}
```

**Edited:**
If we use query string, we can use the type as GET.

But we are using POST method, so we need to pass the data with the param "data".

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

When posting data in query string use the content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/api/APIDirectory/GetDirectoryInfo?reqPath=" + @ViewBag.Title,
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
});
```

*Also, make sure that the ajax syntax is correct (I use jQuery in my example) and that the @ViewBag is not included in the string.*

Then add the [FromUri] parameter in the controller to make sure the binding reads from the uri

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetDirectoryInfo([FromUri]string reqPath)
{   
    string requestPath = reqPath;
    // some code here..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did few things to call an API(server) from AJAX call(Client)
Here is my code
The API controller action:

```
[Route("Create")] //POST
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(string StudentName, int age, string Address)
        {
            try
            {
                 //Your code here
                return Ok(new { Message = "Record Added" });
            }
            catch (Exception ef)
            {

                return BadRequest(ef.Message);
            }
        }
```

The Client ajax call:

```
function SaveData() {
                debugger;
                var n = $('#StudentName').val();
                var a = parseInt($('#age').val());
                var ad = $('#Address').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:5128/api/Students/Create?StudentName='+n+'&age='+a+'&Address='+ad,
                    contentType: 'json',
                    //data: { studentName: n, age:a , address:ad},
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.length == 0) {
                            alert(response);
                        } else {
                            alert("Data Saved!");
                            };
                        },
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
               });
            }
```