# Pass parameter to controller from view using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I need to pass a few parameters from **view** to **Controller** using **JavaScript AJAX**.

Following is my code for the **JavaScript**:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#PaidMonth').on('change', function () {
            var deviceid = $('#PaidMonth').val();
            alert(deviceid);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: { PaidMonth: deviceid },
                url: 'http://localhost:8089/HRM/PaidSalary/id?EmpName',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
                    vehicle = $("#MonthOfSalary").val();
                    console.log(vehicle);
                },
                async: true // make it true if you want to make an async call.
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need to pass the data to controller:

```
public ActionResult PaidSalary(Int64 id, String EmpName, DateTime? PaidMonth)
```

I need id, Empname, PaidMonth which I will be passing from the View.

Also, please don't mark the question as Duplicate as I am not able to find appropriate result.

Comment: deviceid need to be in datetime format

Comment: or else take `PaidMonth` as string and convert it in to DateTime in controller menthod PaidSalary

Comment: Please see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408150/how-to-pass-parameter-from-ajax-request-to-web-api-controller

Comment: could u plz add your view?

Comment: You have to pass all the parameters that the method is expecting or it won't resolve the method signature to the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

Below code could help you to fix your problem.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#PaidMonth').on('change', function () {
        var deviceid = $('#PaidMonth').val();
        alert(deviceid);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: 121, EmpName: "Emp_Name", PaidMonth: deviceid}),
            url: 'http://localhost:8089/HRM/PaidSalary',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
                vehicle = $("#MonthOfSalary").val();
                console.log(vehicle);
            },
            async: true // make it true if you want to make an async call.
        });
    });
});
```